# How to Run for Periodic Detections with Android Beacon Library

Tags: android, background, bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon, scanning

In the http://www.davidgyoungtech.com/2017/08/07/beacon-detection-with-android-8
I want to do test "The New Way: Periodic Detections"

o used program : A reference application for the Android Beacon Library in the 
                 https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library-reference

o my settting for periodic test in the BeaconReferenceApplication.java

```
    ~~ skip ~~
    beaconManager.enableForegroundServiceScanning(builder.build(), 456); // not sure to use or not
    beaconManager.setEnableScheduledScanJobs(true);   // Changed to true for a scheduled job
    beaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(0);
    beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(15*60*1000); // 15min

    beaconManager.setForegroundBetweenScanPeriod(0);  
    beaconManager.setForegroundScanPeriod(1100);

    // Android limits the frequency of scheduled jobs to be at most every 15 minutes
    // when an app is on the background. So any setting smaller than 15 minutes will automatically
    // be converted by the operating system to run every 15 minutes


    Region region = new Region("entrance",
            Identifier.parse("BCFABEFC-B1F5-4836-5152-7C5412FFF9C4"),
            Identifier.fromInt(20200), Identifier.fromInt(101)); 
    Region region2 = new Region("lobby",
            Identifier.parse("BCFABEFC-B1F5-4836-5152-7C5412FFF9C4"),
            Identifier.fromInt(20200), Identifier.fromInt(102)); 

    List<Region> regions = new ArrayList<>();
    regions.add(region);
    regions.add(region2);

    regionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this, regions);
    ~~ skip ~~
```

Question(1): when run with the above setting, I wait more than 25 minutes and nothing comes out in debug. 
             How to do for periodic ScheduledScanJobs in background ?

Comment: Tr beaconManager.setDebug(true); Then you should see logs from your app every ~15min.

Comment: davidyoung, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

These will help to have scheduled scans

```
  beaconManager.setEnableScheduledScanJobs(true); # with this marked true , you will not be able to run background service

  beaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(200l);  beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(1100);
```

## Foreground scan periods

```
   beaconManager.setForegroundScanPeriod(100);beaconManager.setEnableScheduledScanJobs(true);
```